# Django No module named django.core.management

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I was able to run the local server using `python manage.py runserver` in the command line; when I tried the command I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I haven't uninstalled django or edited any of the source code because everything was working fine yesterday. I don't understand what happened.

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: update django, and are you using virtualenv ?

Comment: Has to be the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall django and reinstall it again.

That might solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may have Django but you are using a Python version which doesn't have Django in its `site-packages` folder. Check which version you are using and on which version you have installed Django. You might have change your default Python interpreter since yesterday:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>>>

[...]
$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 23 2012, 16:48:24)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Here I have Django in my Python 2.7 `site-packages` folder but not on Python 3 and it can't find any `django` module in my `PYTHONPATH` then.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer here helped me to resolve the issue here : https://serverfault.com/questions/994651/django-import-error-while-installing-tacker-via-devstack-no-module-named-django/997498#997498